# Missing methods in .netcore5.0 version 1.0.0-preview2-003131

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to build an .netcore5.0 (sdk version"1.0.0-preview2-003131") library and I am trying to access Type.GetTypeCode(), MemberTypes.Field, Type.GetTypeInfo().FindMembers() methods but they are missing from the System.Type library.

The methods were accessible/available in previous version of .netcore5.0 (sdk version "1.0.0-preview2-003121).

Is there any other library where I can use the above methods?

Comment: `Type.GetTypeInfo().GetTypeCode()`. Always get the type info first.

Comment: @LexLi I am in need of TypeCode from the Type object, is the TypeCode removed from the latest .netcore in Type Class?

Comment: go to http://source.dot.net and learn. `Type` is split to `Type` and `TypeInfo`.

Comment: `netcore50` is outdated. For a library, you should switch to `netstandard`.